# MapReduce count the number of occurrence rows

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

At the moment, I have a user_follower.csv such as:

```
user  follower
a       b
a       c
a       b
b       a
b       c
```

I am trying to perform mapreduce where after applying mapreduce, I can have an output like this:

```
user   follower  counts
a         b        2
a         c        1
b         a        1
b         c        1
```

I am quite a beginner with mapreduce concept and writing python script in vim in the command line. This is what I have to get the output but however got the `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

```
import sys
from collections import Counter

counts= Counter('user')   

for line in sys.stdin: 
    data = line.strip()
    user, follower = data
    counts[line] += 1
    sys.stdout.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(user,follower,counts))
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming in line `user, follower = data`. Here it is expecting you to put two values so that it can unpack like `user, follower = data[0],data[1]`. So that `user = data[0]` and `follower=data[1]`. I hope you understood.

This works like `a,b = x,y` so that **a** can have value **x** and **b** can have value **y**.

Answer (score 0):

Few insights -

- When you print `sys.stdout.write("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\n".format(user,follower,counts))` inside the loop it will print the current value of `counts` for all the data.
- When you initialize `counts= Counter('user')` the result is `Counter({'u': 1, 's': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1})`
- After `line.strip()`, `data` is just a string with no extra white spaces. You need to split it in order to assign it to `user` and `follower`'

One possible solution -

```
counts= Counter()   

for line in sys.stdin: 
    data = line.strip()
    user, follower = data.split("\t")
    counts[(user, follower)] += 1

for (user, follower), cnt in counts.items()
    print(f"{user}\t{follower}\t{cnt}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data=line.split(" ")
user, follower = data[0], data[1]
```

In mapreduce generally we use 2 files. In map file output 1 for each user-follower pair and in reduce file peform the aggregation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I tried that and still received the error "IndexError: list index out of range"